java.lang.StackOverflowError: null when displaying a table with its dependencies
I have 3 tables connected to each other. And when I try to display a table with its dependencies, I get an error java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Person {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
    private List<Tool> toolsList;
    
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "tool")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Tool {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "tool_name")
    private String tool_name;

    @Column(name = "cost")
    private int cost;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Person person;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "brand_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Brand brand;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "brand")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Brand {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "brand_name")
    private String brandName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "brand")
    private List<Tool> toolList;
}

@GetMapping("/report")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getReport() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new BodyResponse(HttpStatus.OK.toString(), "People report: " + personService.getPersons().toString() + "\n"
                + "Brand report: " + brandService.getBrands().toString() + "\n"
        + "Instrument report: " + toolService.getTools().toString()), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

I'm trying to run this code and I'm getting the following errors
2024-05-09T13:05:38.723+03:00 ERROR 8996 --- [CrudSecurityRestApplication] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:589) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453) ~[na:na]
    at com.slizokav.MusicToolsRestApi.model.Person.toString(Person.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453) ~[na:na]
    at com.slizokav.MusicToolsRestApi.model.Tool.toString(Tool.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4220) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:173) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:590) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453) ~[na:na]
    at com.slizokav.MusicToolsRestApi.model.Person.toString(Person.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453) ~[na:na]
    at com.slizokav.MusicToolsRestApi.model.Tool.toString(Tool.java:10) ~[classes/:na]

I looked that it has to do with bidirectional relation and lombook annotations, but I changed @Data to @Setter and @Getter and got this output
enter image description here
This is how I made the toString method in the Brand and Person class and still the error occurs
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Person{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", username='" + username + '\'' +
            ", password='" + password + '\'' +
            ", role='" + role + '\'' +
            ", toolsList=" + toolsList.toString() +
            '}';
}

I made this toString when I changed the @Data annotation to @Getter and @Setter

Does this answer your question? Why is this toString() method causing StackOverFlowError?

Person has a List of Tool and Tool has a reference of Person. So, when you invoke toString() of Tool inside the definition of toString() of Person the call goes to the Tool and there it invokes toString() of Person and this becomes an infinite loop causing Stackoverflow error

Please write an answer with a code example

In your case, you need to change the toString method in the Person and Brand classes to the following code:
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Person {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "username")
private String username;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "role")
private String role;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
private List<Tool> toolsList;

public Person(String username, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Person{" +
            "role='" + role + '\'' +
            ", password='" + password + '\'' +
            ", username='" + username + '\'' +
            ", id=" + id +
            '}';
}

}
And therefore for the Brand class
@Entity
@Table(name = "brand")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Brand {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "brand_name")
private String brandName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "brand")
private List<Tool> toolList;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Brand{" +
            "brandName='" + brandName + '\'' +
            ", id=" + id +
            '}';
}

}

I shouldn't answer this as I'm the one who suggested this one as a duplicate, but since you asked I'm posting this. Consider two entities
public class A {

    B b = new B();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "A [b=" + b + "]";
    }
}

and
public class B {

    A a = new A();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "B [a=" + a + "]";
    }
}

You can see that there is a reference to B in A and vice-versa.
Now let's define a Test class
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println(new A());
    }
}

Whenever we try to print a reference of a class the toString() of that class is invoked. So,
Step-1: The toString() of A is invoked which is defined as "A [b=" + b + "]". Now, inside that we are printing the reference of B, to automatically the toString() of B will be invoked
Step-2: The toString() of B is getting invoked which is defined as "B [a=" + a + "]", again there we are printing the reference of A, so the call goes back to Step-1 and then again to Step-2 and becomes a non-ending loop.
Every call is sent to the Stack, so after some time the Stack will be full and the next call will give StackOverflowError.
